# Which database to use for C# ASP.NET website?

Tags: asp.net, database, visual-studio-2008, iis, forms

I am developing an online internal web portal (like users write tests, provide document links to study, completing a study roadmap, admin user to view ststistics, etc). It caters some 150 users. I have planned to use **ASP .NET** with **c#** in Visual Studio 2008 on windows xp. I am implementing using **Forms** and **NOT MVC** since I feel at home with forms.
I do not want to use windows authentication since each user will have many attributes related to him and so it will be easy using a database. Security is not an issue since it is being used internally only. 
I have only a fair knowledge about ASP and C# and VS 2008.

**Now my questions:**
Can I use MS SQL server database that is built in in VS 2008?( I cannot ask for external databases)
Can I export the website totally along with the databases to IIS server running in some other computer? How?
Do I need to export databases separately or provide a database creation script like PHP?

(I have more questions. Will update once I start off).
(This is my first .net web app. so can i know where i can find login scripts, pagination, examples, and pretty much all the stuff)

edit: which to use? New website or New Webapplication?

Comment: As a side note, saying "security is not an issue because it is internally used" is a blessing for any attacker. :)

Comment: oh i understand that ;) I mean, it does not need to be very secure... no sensitive data in the website.

Comment: Still not a good attitude to have and the website itself might not have sensitive data but the server it is hosted on MIGHT.

Comment: oh! yeah! never thought of that! You enlightened me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pretty much use any database, but it seems from your requirements that you want to look closer towards something like [SQLExpress](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/), [SQL Server Compact Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/compact.aspx) or [SQLLite](http://www.sqlite.org/).

> Can I export the website totally along
>   with the databases to IIS server
>   running in some other computer? How?

Your database will be shipped along with your application if you use one of the database options that I have specified above.

> Do I need to export databases
>   separately or provide a database
>   creation script like PHP?

See my comment above, the database will exist when you deploy your website to IIS. It's a physical file that will be in your APP_DATA folder.

Comment: ok. Then I will start off with inbuilt SQL server database of VS 2008.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

1. MySQL. The reason: It has no space or memory limit!
2. SQL Server or SQL CE. These are both alike. They just differ in slite functions, and also the storage!
   The SQL CE allows you to have 4GB. But the SQL Server lets you have 10GB.

So it depends on your work!

Also, I wanted to point out one error in a post, that the SQL CE is present in App_Data, Correct! But the SQL Server is placed somewhere like:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\here_will_it_be

And yes, you can migrate it to wherever you want to place it. I mean if you want to upload it to a hosting server, you can upload it using Web Deploy! Or what ever service. When downloading you will have to repeat same process!

I hope you are doing good with your first web app! :)